# can I populate data from sqlite into a gridPane?

Tags: sqlite, javafx, drag-and-drop, gridpane

I know you can populate date from database into a tableView, edit its values and drag and drop rows, but what I need to is get data from database and and drag and drop from cell to cell, I am thinking if I am able to populate data into an empty gridPane, this maybe possible? please help!

Comment: Why can't you drag and drop from cell to cell in a table view?

Comment: I did not find examples on how to do it, any tutorial or example would be nice to see. thanks.